# how to call the .aar file activity from parent activity in android studio when a button is clicked in parent app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent, aar

I am trying to import the .aar in the parent app, the .aar file contains multiple activities and functions,
what I am trying to do here is imported the aar file in the libs folder which is present in the app[directly pasted inside] folder, and then implemented it in build Gradle, but I am getting an android resource link failed.

You can check these images of what I have done in the coding part

this is the error i am getting
[image: Error Image]

and this is how I called the libs folder

[image: Implemented in gradle]

I called the lib folder like this

[image: setting gradle]
[image: gradle]

In the manifest file, I try to call the activity like this

[image: parentmanifist]

in the child manifest I commented on the activity tag, it showed duplicate

[image: aar file manifist]

can anyone help me to fix this issue, when I click a button in parent activity which is in mainactivity.kt it should go to child activity which is present in aar file, named HomeActivity.

both manifest files
[image: manifest]

This the new error i am getting

```
  Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 9182
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/live.hms.app2.ui.home.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #46 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_home: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

which is

[image: activity_main]

Answer (score 0):

The aar file has it own manifest file in it. You don't need to decare `HomeActivity` in the manifest file of app module. Android studio can help you merge all the manifest files into one file.

Just directly use `HomeActivity` in `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: if i do like that also i am getting error [Unresolved reference: HomeActivity] in main activity, because I am not able to import home activity in the main activity for intent

Comment: How about this?  val intent = Intent(live.hms.app2.ui.home.HomeActivity::class.java)

Comment: Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. 

getting error like this when i rebuild the app with you line of code

Comment: You should add android:exported="false" to HomeActivity declaration and generate the aar file again.

Comment: back to the same error but merger failed fixed
AAPT: error: resource color/colorPrimary (aka com.example.myapplication:color/colorPrimary) not found.

Comment: Add one color in colors.xml:  <color name="colorPrimary">#000000</color>

Comment: ok i tried , it fixed,but getting new errors,
AAPT: error: attribute navGraph (aka com.example.myapplication:navGraph) not found.

its all in aar file is there is any way to fix that at once, because there are two more issue related to android resource not linked

Comment: It seems that there are some error in app module. Don't  the include aar file before you fix all errors in app module.  As for the error "attribute navGraph not found" , this may be helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69880489/2173056

Comment: bro, i tried that all errors fixed, but while clicking the button the app is getting crashed

[ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/viewbinding/ViewBinding;]

Comment: To enable viewBinding, add "buildFeatures { viewBinding = true }" to  build.gradle in the  "android {  ...  } "

Comment: i added it bro, but the app is not launching automatically when i run through android studio, and it shows two with the same name, when i uninstall it removes both, and after putting viewb = true, when i click the button it lanches the home activity but not showing any content

Comment: 1. Maybe home activity is also the laucher activity?  2. Is home activity's content view 
 blank?

Comment: yes bro, but while launching the app it goes to permission fragment, now it not going to permission fragment, i updated my question with two manifest file pics, please see that if you can find do some thing

Comment: If your target sdk vertion is larger than 22(>22), you should request these sensitive
permission(AUDIO, BLUETOOTH, CAMERA etc.) programmatically.  https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: ok bro but child app separately working fine without any issues, after intagrating to parent app only i am facing like this issue

Comment: Maybe the app module and child module has different target sdk version.

Comment: yes, bro in the child app the target SDK version is 30, and in parent app tar. SDK ver.  is 31, so I changed to 30 in the parent app, but it did not change anything in the app. in the child app the compiled SDK version is 30, and in the parent app it's 31 when I changed to 30 it showing error like this[ the mincompilesdk (31) specified in a dependency's aar metadata android ]

Comment: Recover it. And what's the targetSdkVersion of the child app?

Comment: its 30 in child app, -

hey bro, i thought of replacing res-auto to res only in activities xml, but i find it also present in other xml file also so i deleted it, now i getting error like this [Too many arguments for public final fun actionHomeFragmentToSettingsFragment(): NavDirections defined in live.hms.app2.ui.home.HomeFragmentDirections.Companion]

Comment: that error i am getting in child app before generating aar file

Comment: You mean xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"? No need to change it.

Comment: i tried this link [this may be helpful: stackoverflow.com/a/69880489/2173056] bro which you gave, which i got fixed AAPT: error: attribute navGraph (aka com.example.myapplication:navGraph) so only i tred removing all res-auto

Comment: So that answer not works for you. Do you add the navigation-ui library to your app module? Can app module run OK without the aar? Make sure the app module is OK at first.

Comment: I reversed everything bro, to res-auto, while running the parent app on button click , it getting crashed, [ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 9051
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/live.hms.app2.ui.home.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #46 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_home: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView]

Comment: Your app module has too many useless things. Discard it, and add a new app2 module , and choose "Empty Activity"  : https://imgur.com/a/kOLX2RO.

Comment: not like that bro it used MVVM concept with navhost package so only getting errors like this, if i fix this navigation part the app will work fine, so only i am trying to fix it

Comment: Maybe you should add implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.1' . FragmentContainerView class is in this library.

Comment: i tried to put in child app, and build the aar, but its the same result getting crashed on button click

Comment: Put it in app module's build.gradle. Because it seems that activity_home.xml is in app module (com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_home). Or activity_home.xml should not be in app module. HomeActivity's layout file is already in the aar.

Comment: parent app module or child app module[aar], i tried that in child app module by implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.1'. same result, should i have to try in parent module

Comment: If activity_home.xml exists in child module, then you don't need to add it to parent module.

Comment: I had updated the question with the recent error, please check it, if you can find anything.